# How to check if the current tab is the last tab?

Tags: vimscript

As title. I want to check that if current tab is the last (rightmost) tab, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `tabpagenr()` function, which returns the number of the current tab page when called without any arguments, or the last tab page number when called with a `'$'`.

The following expression should tell you whether you're on the last tab:

```
tabpagenr() == tabpagenr('$')
```